# Where can I publish corrigenda for a conference paper?

Tags: publications

I am wondering where I should publish a corrigendum. The paper, which has some wrong numbers in it (nothing major but it still is not correct), has been published in conference proceedings. I don't think a journal would publish a corrigendum for a mere conference article, submitting to the same conference next year does not seem to be the right way to do it either (takes too long, I don't know if they would accept it since there would be not much of a presentation). So I am thinking of a technical report. Would that be a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

If the proceedings is one that was issued by the conference at the same time as the conference (or shortly thereafter), you may be stuck with just publishing it on your website, which is presumably what you meant by a tech report. If the conference was run by a major society, you may at least be able to get the online version of the proceedings updated. You should get in touch with the program chair for the conference at the very least.